# Laravel Passport unsupported_grant_type

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

I have been stuck on Laravel Passport issue for 4 days now.
Following is my code base to verify login credentials and thus verify user login (token based)

I have followed all the steps for Passport integration.

API I call (From Postman): 
http://localhost/oauth/token/?email=admin@test.com&password=Abcd@123&grant_type=password&client_id=10&client_secret=xqVaBzFyC2fVDwyd6Pk7nsy2o45GfYAgUKeR2OjK&scope=*

i.e.

```
email:admin@test.com
password:Abcd@123
grant_type:password
client_id:3
client_secret:xqVaBsdfsdfsf42fso45GfYAgUKeR2OjK
scope:*
```

config/auth.php

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

But I am getting the error :

```
{
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
  "message": "The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server.",
  "hint": "Check the `grant_type` parameter"
}
```

Error I received

```
[2017-03-08 12:12:10] local.ERROR: League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException: The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server. in /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/Exception/OAuthServerException.php:65
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/AuthorizationServer.php(204): League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException::unsupportedGrantType()
#1 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/passport/src/Http/Controllers/AccessTokenController.php(63): League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationServer->respondToAccessTokenRequest(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
#2 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/passport/src/Http/Controllers/HandlesOAuthErrors.php(25): Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController->Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\{closure}()
#3 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/passport/src/Http/Controllers/AccessTokenController.php(64): Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController->withErrorHandling(Object(Closure))
#4 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(47): Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController->issueToken(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest))
#5 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(203): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController), 'issueToken')
#6 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(160): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController()
#7 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(559): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run()
#8 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#11 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(561): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#14 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(520): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(498): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(174): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/app/Http/Middleware/ResponseLogger.php(22): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): App\Http\Middleware\ResponseLogger->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#20 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/app/Http/Middleware/RequestLogger.php(45): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): App\Http\Middleware\RequestLogger->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#23 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/app/Http/Middleware/Cors.php(18): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): App\Http\Middleware\Cors->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#27 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#29 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#32 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#33 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#34 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#35 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#36 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#37 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#38 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#39 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#40 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#41 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#42 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#43 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#44 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#45 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#46 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(149): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#47 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#48 /var/www/html/test/testProj/Proj_Latest/public/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#49 {main}
```

---

Now since this did not work, I tried the method :

```
Auth::attempt(array('email' => 'admin@test.com', 'password' => 'Abcd@123'))
```

**But this time I received :**

> [2017-03-08 12:00:00] local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::attempt() in /var/www/html/..../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php:294

Nothing seems to be working in Laravel 5.4

Comment: How do you send the data in Postman? form-data or perhaps x-www-form-urlencoded ?

Comment: Tried both ways. Also tried in URL params. All result to unsupported_grant_type

Comment: Do you have the Auth Basic token or credentials sent in the header from Postman? Example: `Authorization: Basic aHR0cHdhdGNoOmY=`

Comment: No.. since this API is to retrieve the token, so I have not set any token in the headers

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that the grant client is a 'password client', creaded similiarly as with the command:

```
php artisan passport:client --password
```

This means that the 'password_client' column in the database has the value '1' next to the corresponding client.
I also struggled a lot with the default user clients created from the user interface, and it doesn't work with those.

Answer (score -1):

[you got to send the request with raw as parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBQ8K.png)

you got to send the request with raw as parameters

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34863552)